# Loop over items und wrap items into div container using jquery each function

Tags: javascript, loops, each

My Html

```
<div class="loop">
<article>1<article>
<article>2<article>
<article>3<article>
<article>4<article>
<article>5<article>
<article>6<article>
</div>
```

My JS:

```
 $('.loop').find('article').each(function (index, section) {
            if ( index < 3) {
                      
                // code here 

        }
   })
```

I have no idea how to solve this:

I want to iterate over these items and wrap item 1,2,3 with a div. Also item 4,5,6  and 7,8,9 (if there are more items)

My desired Html would be:

```
<div class="loop">
<div="newContainer">
    <article>1<article>
    <article>2<article>
    <article>3<article>
</div>
<div="newContainer">
    <article>4<article>
    <article>5<article>
    <article>6<article>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you do with <div="newContainer">? Did you mean <div id="newContainer">?

Answer (score 1):

I write a solution for you:

```
$('.loop').find('article').each(function (index, section) {
    if(index % 3 ===0)
     {
       $('.loop').append($('<div>'));
     }
     $('.loop').children(`div:nth-of-type(${Math.floor(index/3)+1})`).first().append(section);
})
```

here is a full example:
https://jsfiddle.net/t40ujrbs/

Answer (score 0):

Another way you could do this would be to also use `wrapAll` inside of your `each`.

```js
var article = $('article');

$.each(article, function (index, section) {
  if (index % 3 === 0) {
    $(article).slice(index, index + 3).wrapAll("<div class='new-div'>Test text</div>");
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="loop">
  <article>1</article>
  <article>2</article>
  <article>3</article>
  <article>4</article>
  <article>5</article>
  <article>6</article>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer a longer, but simpler to understand solution, you can do this.

```js
$(document).ready(()=>{
  let newDiv = $("<div>");
  let generalId=1, ctrl=3;
  let dv = $("<div>");
  dv.attr("id", "new-container"+generalId);
  let oldDiv=$(".loop");

  oldDiv.find("article").each(function (index, article) {
    ctrl--;
    dv.append(article);

    if(ctrl==0) {// if ctrl==0, we will append to new main div
      newDiv.append(dv);
      generalId++;
      dv = $("<div>");
      dv.attr("id", "new-container"+generalId);
      ctrl=3;
    }
  });
  if(ctrl>0) newDiv.append(dv);
  oldDiv.html(newDiv.html());
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
</head>
<body>
  <div class="loop">
    <article>1</article>
    <article>2</article>
    <article>3</article>
    <article>4</article>
    <article>5</article>
    <article>6</article>
    <article>7</article>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very helpful!

Comment: @Milenoi, i am happy to know that it is useful. May you vote to help other people? Tks!

Comment: Unfortunately i can not do this -  i get this message:  "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." Sorry  for that ;(